# Update modified fields of an item only

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

My `Car` entity has the following properties:

```
Name,
Color, 
CreationDate
```

I'm using this code to update my `Car` item:

```
using (MyContextEntities db = new MyContextEntities())
{
     db.Entry(Car).State = EntityState.Modified;
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, when the user only updates the `Name` and `Color` of my `Car` item, the item `CreationDate` turns to "`0001/01/01`".

How can I tell the EF to only update the modified fields and keep those that weren't modified as is?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you modify the model? Are you creating a new one with the same ID and just setting the modified properties? How are you doing the bindings?

Answer (score 1):

You could go:

```
using (MyContextEntities db = new MyContextEntities())
{
     db.Entry(Car).State = EntityState.Modified;
     db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.CreationDate).IsModified=false;
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or you might consider using ViewModels that have only the properties you want to modify.